# Fetch some data from Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I'm saving some data - name and surname. But i don't know how to fetch some data.
Here is my code, but i don't know why it doesn't work - i don't know

```
class UserIN: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String?

}
```

I create NSManagedObject Subclass

```
func fetching(){
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let usersFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")

        do {
            let fetchedUsers = try context.fetch(usersFetch) as! [UserIN]
            print(fetchedUsers)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
        }

    }
```

Please tell me the reason why it doesn't display fetched data.

Comment: The class name by default is the same as the entity name. Did you change the class name? If so, you have to set it in the data model to say that the entity refers to this class.

Comment: Please show how you create (save) the data.

Answer (score 0):

The class of the `NSManagedObject` subclass must match the name of the entity (unless you changed it manually in Interface Builder)

```
class Users: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String?

}
```

Not related to the issue but in Swift 3 use a fetch request with static type rather than the generic `NSFetchRequestResult`:

```
func fetching(){
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let usersFetch = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")

    do {
        let fetchedUsers = try context.fetch(usersFetch)
        print(fetchedUsers)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch employees: \(error)")
    }

}
```